# how to add image to plot mplfinance python

Tags: python, mplfinance

Trying to add image and price label and add more space on time and it seems like ylim= takes care of that but when i add it my whole graph disappears.

```
    market_colors = mpf.make_marketcolors(
        base_mpf_style="charles"
    )
    rc = {
        "axes.labelcolor": "none",
        "axes.spines.bottom": True,
        "axes.spines.left": False,
        "axes.spines.right": False,
        "axes.spines.top": False,
        "font.size": 10,
    }
    styles = mpf.make_mpf_style(
        base_mpf_style="nightclouds",
        marketcolors=market_colors,
        gridstyle="",
        rc=rc
    )

    filledShape = {
        "y1": df['Close'].values,
        "facecolor": "#2279e4"
    }

    (mpf.plot(df, type='line',
              title='Test',
              linecolor='white',
              style=styles,
              volume=True,
              figsize=(8, 6),
              figscale=0.5,
              fill_between=filledShape, tight_layout=True,
              scale_padding={'left': 1, 'top': 5, 'right': 1, 'bottom': 2}
              ))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are three techniques that I know of to display an image on a matplotlib plot:

1. [Axes.imshow()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow.html)
2. [Figure.figimage()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html?highlight=figure%20figure#matplotlib.figure.Figure.figimage)
3. [Putting the image in an `AnnotationBbox`](https://moonbooks.org/Articles/How-to-insert-an-image-a-picture-or-a-photo-in-a-matplotlib-figure/)

In terms of working with mplfinance, I would say that technique one, calling **[Axes.imshow()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow.html)** is probably simplest:

##### Step 1:

For all three of the above techniques, when you call `mpf.plot()` set kwarg `returnfig=True`:

```py
fig axlist = mpf.plot(df,...,returnfig=True)
```

This will give you [access to the mplfinance Figure and Axes objects](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/wiki/Acessing-mplfinance-Figure-and-Axes-objects).

##### Step 2:

Now create a new Axes object where you want the image/logo:

```py
# Note: [left,bottom,width,height] are in terms of fraction of the Figure.
# For example [0.05,0.08,0.10,0.06] means:
#  the lower/left corner of the Axes will be located: 
#    5% of the way in from the left
#    8% down from the top,
#  and the Axes will be
#    10% of the Figure wide and
#    6% of the Figure high.

logo_axes = fig.add_axes([left,bottom,width,height])
```

##### Step 3:

Read in the image:

```py
import Image
im = Image.open('image_file_name.png')
```

##### Step 4:

Call imshow() on the newly created Axes, and turn of the axis lines:

```py
logo_axes.imshow(im)
logo_axes.axis('off')
```

##### Step 5:

Since `returnfig=True` causes mplfinance to *not* show the Figure, call `mpf.show()`

```py
mpf.show()
```

Comment: I am looking at the answers from the experts, am I approaching this wrong?

Comment: Such detailed explanations are of value to users of mpf. +1

Comment: @r-beginners ... your approach is fine.  as mentioned above `Figure.figimage()` is one of the three techniques that I know of for placing an image on a Figure.  And truthfully it's about as easy as `Axes.imshow()` (shown above in detail).  Only the `AnnotationBbox` technique gets a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answer will help you or not since I'm not sure what kind of images you want to add. I assume you want to add a corporate logo or something like that, so I did some research and found an [answer](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/issues/164) to whether you can add a watermark to an mpf. I used this answer as a guide and added the icons used on [stackoveflow.com](https://stackoverflow.design/brand/logo/) to the graph. However, it was not possible to add them to the axes, so I had to add them to the fig. I have changed the style to add the image.

```
img = plt.imread('./data/se-icon.png')

market_colors = mpf.make_marketcolors(
        base_mpf_style="charles"
    )
rc = {
    "axes.labelcolor": "none",
    "axes.spines.bottom": True,
    "axes.spines.left": False,
    "axes.spines.right": False,
    "axes.spines.top": False,
    "font.size": 10,
}
styles = mpf.make_mpf_style(
    base_mpf_style="yahoo",# nightclouds
    marketcolors=market_colors,
    gridstyle="",
    rc=rc
)

filledShape = {
    "y1": df['Close'].values,
    "facecolor": "#2279e4"
}

fig, axes = mpf.plot(df, type='line',
                     title='Test',
                     linecolor='white',
                     style=styles,
                     volume=True,
                     figsize=(8, 6),
                     figscale=0.5,
                     fill_between=filledShape,
                     tight_layout=True,
                     scale_padding={'left': 1, 'top': 5, 'right': 1, 'bottom': 2},
                     returnfig=True
)

#axes[0].imshow(img)
#height = img.shape[1]

fig.figimage(img, 0, fig.bbox.ymax - height*1.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Also, I didn't quite understand what you wanted to do with the x-axis space reservation.